# Dynamic password authentication

Tags: password, authentication

I would like to know how can I (and if it's possible) create a dynamic authentication for a user in linux.

The server would change the user password periodically and the user would use a program (like a token) to retrieve and enter the correct password.

Comment: What application were you thinking of using this for?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you're looking for but I've seen OTPW used for such scenarios. It's a complete package that integrates with a Linux system via PAM modules.

- http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/otpw.html

*excerpt*

> The OTPW package consists of the one-time-password generator `otpw-gen` plus two verification routines `otpw_prepare()` and `otpw_verify()` that can easily be added to programs such as `login` or `ftpd` on POSIX systems. For platforms that support the Pluggable Authentication Method (PAM) interface, a suitable wrapper is included as well. Login software extended this way will allow reasonably secure user authentication over insecure network lines. The user carries a password list on paper. The scheme is designed to be robust against theft of the paper list and race-for-the-last-letter attacks. Cryptographic hash values of the one-time passwords are stored for verification in the user’s home directory.

In your case you'll want to follow the directions on that page detailing the PAM installation.

*excerpt*

> If your system supports Pluggable Authentication Modules [Mor01,XSSO], then simply compile the shared library `pam_otpw.so` and copy it to the directory in which other PAM modules reside (under Linux usually `/lib/security/`). Then edit the PAM configuration file for the application in which you want to use OTPW, as described in your PAM System Administrators’ Guide. The `pam_otpw.so` provides both an authentication and a session component. The authentication component asks for and verifies a one-time password, the session component prints after each successful login a reminder on how many unused passwords you have left.
>
> To use both components when login into your system via Secure Shell, you might have to add in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` the lines
>
> ```
>  auth            required        pam_otpw.so
>  session         optional        pam_otpw.so
> ```
>
> With OpenSSH 3.4 for example, you need to make sure that your version has PAM support compiled in, and you will have to add in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` the lines
>
> ```
>  UsePrivilegeSeparation          no
>  PAMAuthenticationViaKbdInt      yes
> ```
>
> To force OpenSSH to use PAM authentication (instead of its own hostbased or publickey methods, which it normally tries first), use `“ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive”`.